# Downwards and Upwards events

Tags: angular

I'm trying angular 2 and I think it is great! 
But I cannot figure out how to emit/subscribe to events.

For instance:
I have two little components: componentA and componentB. 
ComponentA contains a list of fruits. ComponentB contains the details of a fruit. When a user select a fruit from the list (componentA) I want ComponentB to execute a function (e.g. console.log(event)).

To achieve this behaviour I would like to use events.
ComponentA is not the parent of componentB, they are brothers. But I want the event to propagate downwards and also upwards.
Anyone who know the name of the event must be able to subscribe to this event.

Is it possible?
I would like to use the angular2 classes, not external libraries.

My current code:

```ts
export class ComponentA
{
    @Output() emitter: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter();

    private onFruitSelected():void
    {
        this.emitter.emit ("Hello!");
    }
}


export class ComponentA
{
    constructor ():void
    {
        // subscribe doJob() to the event
    }

    private doJob ():void { console.log('event catched'); }
}
```

Thanks!

**EDIT**

I updated the code in this way:

Event handler service:

```ts
export class EventEmitterService 
{
    @Output() eventOne: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter();
    @Output() eventTwo: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter();
}
```

componentA (event sender):

```ts
export class ComponentA
{
    public constructor(private eventHandler:EventEmitterService) {}

    private onFruitSelected():void
    {
        this.emitter.emit ("Hello!");
        this.eventHandler.eventOne.emit ("Hello event one");
        this.eventHandler.eventTwo.emit (12);
    }
}
```

componentB (event receiver):

```ts
export class ComponentA
{
    constructor ():void
    {
        eventHandler.eventOne.subscribe ((evt:string) => { 
            console.log ('Event one ' + evt); 
        });

        eventHandler.eventTwo.subscribe ((evt:number) => { 
            console.log ('Event two ' + evt); 
        });
    }
}
```

Is this a good solution?

Answer (score 0):

Angular2 doesn't provide a feature for that. 
You can use a custom event bus service.
See also

- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/1297
- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/3186
- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/1763

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I just updated my question, what to do you think about by solution? Thanks again!